# Show and Hide a div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By clicking a link, I want to display a div `.box` which is initially hidden. But if the link is clicked again while the `.box` is visible, I want to hide it then.

I can display with following code but how can I hide it when clicking on the link again?

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
<div class="box" style="display: none">box</div>

$('.link').click(function(e){    
    $('.box').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntfhfsft/

Comment: seriously? why -1? What wrong I have asked here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **[`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)** to toggle between fadeIn and fadeOut. Add **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default action on click event.

**Update :** You can use **[`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to clear the animation queue

```js
$('.link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.box').stop()
    .fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
<div class="box" style="display: none">box</div>
```

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` or a `return false` to prevent weird jumping around/scrolling on the page and the ugly `#` in the address bar :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.link').click(function(e){    
    $('.box').toggle();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ntfhfsft/1/) for reference

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
<div class="box" style="display: none">box</div>
```

You can use toggle method:

```
  $('.link').click(function(e){
        $('.box').toggle('slow');
    });
```

here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntfhfsft/2/)